# JavaScript continuing before function has finished!? Ajax asynchronous confusion and solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I've got a problem. The function below works 100%, but the `if` statement which calls the function resolves before the function returns its result!

The alert for "test2" will show BEFORE the alert with the "result: "+data box does. What is the reason?

(The problem being that it ALWAYS resolves to false no matter what because nothing is returned even when something is going to be returned!)

```
    function checkUsername ( username ) {
        $.post("ajax_messages.php",{
            func: "checkUsername",
            username: username
        }, function(data){
            alert("result: "+data);
            return data;
        });
    }

    $('.send').click( function () {
        if ( checkUsername($receiverBox.val()) == "true" ) {
            alert("test");
            return false;
        } else {
            alert("test2");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Edit:

Thanks for the swift replies. I tried the following:

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
        async:false
    });
```

Edit2: But this also did not act as expected. As a normal set of functions would so I will be expected to act. So I will be trying some more of the methods below

Edit3: Success! This is perfect. A little clumbsy but much much smoother than any other method I could find. I hope this helps

```
    var checkUsernameResult = false;

    function checkErrorCheckingIsComplete( ) {
        if ( checkUsernameResult != false ) {
            alert( checkUsernameResult );
        }
    }

    function checkUsername ( username ) {
        $.post("ajax_messages.php",{
            func: "checkUsername",
            username: username
        }, function(data){
            alert("result: "+data);
            checkUsernameResult = data; // each check has one of these
            checkErrorCheckingIsComplete(); // all checks have this as the end
        });
    }

    $('.send', $message_box).click( function () {
        checkUsername( $receiverBox.val() );
        //more checks here
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have to create another button that performs the submit, because you'll never have the response with Ajax's asynchronous functions.

Add another button to your HTML page with a class "actual-send", and then try this...

```
var asynchResult = "false";
function checkUsername ( username ) {
    $.post("ajax_messages.php",{
        func: "checkUsername",
        username: username
    }, function(data){
        alert("result: "+data);
        asynchResult = data;
        $('.actual-send').trigger('click');
    });
}

$('.send').click( function () {
    checkUsername($receiverBox.val())
    return false;
}
$('.actual-send').click( function () {
    if(asynchResult == "true") {
        alert("test");
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("test2");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: For anyone who reads this in the future, read the edit3 in my question and it'll explain. Thank you for the idea digiguru

Comment: Glad I could help. You might want to get rid of the global variable - I think this can be done be wrapping the following around the javascript code... (function() { <your code here> })();

Comment: Yeah you have to do that with all javascript to prevent that, cheers though

Answer (score 2):

Since AJAX calls are `asynchronous` this happens. Use a callback function for `.post` and put the if statement in that.

The other thing that you can do is to use synchronous calls.But this will stop the browser from executing any other action in the meantime.

Comment: Couldn't OP use $.ajax and set async to false?

Comment: ah so add the check if statement to the callback? I'll try now

Comment: hmm although this will work I can't handle the clicking of the submit box via this method... although I can keep adding the checking deeper and deeper into the code I thought that would be bad practice?

Comment: You can set the `async` attribute to `false` to make it a synchronous call.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used jQuery for a few months, but I am pretty sure you can set a flag to force the Ajax call to happen as a synchronous call.

Comment: $.ajaxSetup({
   async:false
  });

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers said, the post() method is asynchronous so it executes independently of the rest of the code.

If necessary you can force jquery to call the server synchronously using `async:false` instead, I think you'd have to use the [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function instead of the .post() shorthand to do that though.

It generally works much better asynchronously though, as in synchronous mode it will freeze the webpage while it waits for the response from the server - not a great experience for your visitors. A better idea is to keep it in async mode and deal with the server response in the success() callback.

Comment: again as I've mentioned above, although I understand (now) about the async etc and the freezing etc. I am wondering how it is possible to use ajax for error trapping without over nesting (imagine 10 items...)

Answer (score 0):

you can use following:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'ajax_messages.php',
  data: data,
  success: function(html){
   alert(html); 
  }
  dataType: dataType
});
```

so, on POST success execute function which grabs whatever your ajax_messages.php will echo and alerts with it

Comment: This is a way more complicated answer than what Rahul said, and again it forces me to.. whats that word... nest all my dynamic error checking... which isn't what I want really as that is poor practice imo

Answer (score 0):

put asynchronous: false

Comment: You could do this, but bear in mind you will lock the browser while the AJAX is being performed. You will also need to use the AJAX property in jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: yes but is there a way to do it without forcing a user to nest the handler in the callback?

Comment: than what's the purpose of "A" in "A"JAX if you do not use asynchronous ;-)

Comment: I don't mind using asynchronus, I just need to find a way of using it now.